# Why i'm getting an empty array in result of httpget?

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

I have StatsUserModel ( code below )
**StatsUserModel.cs**

```
namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class StatsUserModel
    {
        public int DeviceID { get; set; }
        public int bloodpress_sys { get; set; }
        public int bloodpress_dia { get; set; }
        public int saturation { get; set; }
        public int BPM { get; set; }
        public int veinsdiameter { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And i have Users from AspNetUsers
[AspNetUsers and Stats structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99dHc.png)

**And i have AuthenticationContext.cs**

```
namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AuthenticationContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StatsUserModel> statsUserModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, I have created StatsController and **HttpGet** method
**StatsController.cs**

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StatsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        private AuthenticationContext context;
        public StatsController(AuthenticationContext _context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            context = _context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<Object> GetStats(LoginModel model)
        {
            string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            var data = context.statsUserModels.Where(s => s.Id == user.Id);
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Generating a JWT

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.UserName);
            if(user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password))
            {
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
                    {
                        new Claim("UserID", user.Id.ToString())
                    }),
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_applicationSettings.JWT_Secret)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
                return Ok(new { token });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password invalid" });
            }

        }
```

I use Postman to test login and it's returns me a JWT token and everything works fine, but when i'm passing that login name and password, it returns me an empty array with 200OK code

Comment: I suggest that you could debug the code to check if `userId` contains value or not.And whether you get the `user ` or not.If you do not get the `userId`,please share how did you generate jwt tokens.

Comment: From Output i have :  SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[BPM], [s].[DeviceID], [s].[bloodpress_dia], [s].[bloodpress_sys], [s].[saturation], [s].[veinsdiameter]
WebAPI>       FROM [statsUserModels] AS [s]
WebAPI>       WHERE [s].[Id] = @__user_Id_0

Comment: When the authentication is being processed im getting that : SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Discriminator], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName], [u].[FullName]
WebAPI>       FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]

Comment: You may misunderstand me.You need debug the code in vs to check which line does not query data.For how to debug code:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#set-a-breakpoint-and-start-the-debugger

Comment: So i'm getting the userId, but user and data are null

Comment: So you got it now.Check the database,if the corresponding database table contain such user.

Comment: So i inspected this issue and i see that userId i'm getting is OK, user is OK, and data is `{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<WebAPI.Models.StatsUserModel>}` and what does it mean i don't know :) I used watch tool for debug

Comment: That is because your data is type of IQueryable.You could check the value like below:https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpZBS.gif

Comment: I followed your steps and i have this https://imgur.com/a/NII75of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, i have made Add-Migration and filled the table once more time and everything worked, Thanks Rena !